# External libraries in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a site using react, and I need to install mojs, mojs-timeline, and mojs-curve-editor. None of these are npm packages, what is the best way to include them to be used within react?

I found [this post](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/using-external-script-libraries/2256/2) that looks like it references a helpful article in React's documentation but it has been deleted I guess as it just redirects you to the tutorial page.

I can download the files, or source them externally, whatever is best for this case.

I've seen a lot of talk about using Webpack, but I'm not too familiar with it and my attempts at including it in the Webpack config have been unsuccessful.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to simply `link` them in your index.html file like so...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/path/to/file/or/cdn"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, is there some sort of way I need to reference it in my .js? like `import mojs ...` or something?

Comment: make sure you include the script tag before you include your react code.

Comment: i looked into mojs and it does appear to be on npm

Comment: If it is on npm then a module bundler like webpack or browserify is ideal. For a beginner, you may want to look into [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) as this comes with stock with webpack confiured and ready to roll

Comment: Ah I found it on npm! Sorry about that. I got confused because there is another lib called 'mojs' that is not the same one I am looking for.

It's working good now, you just have to do `import mojs from 'mo-js';` to use it.